# Help figuring out a water pressure problem in new shower faucet installation

Tags: shower, faucet, water-pressure

When installing a Price Pfister Shower head we water hammering. So we got a new cartridge sent to us. Now there is a tiny trickle when we turn the hot water valve on. We switched the cartridges back to the original one and we get zero cold water. Any suggestions on what else it could be? By the way there is zero hammering now with the original cartridge.

Comment: Sounds like the flow restriction device in the head is plugged to me